# Down votes for Answers: reason very low quality question!

Tags: discussion, support

Is it good to do down votes for all answers for a reason that the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168009/i-need-a-solution-for-array-combine-in-php/49168193#49168193) is of less quality?

I do not think so... What about you?
Is it on Stack Rules for down votes.

Got a comment that says:

> You shouldn't have answered. We expect quite a bit more effort from asker's here. I can't imagine how a question can get any worse than this.

Comment: In general, users can vote however they _want_. (Voting rings or serial voting aside). That specific question was a case of _"Write my code for me"_. We don't want to encourage such off-topic questions with answers.

Comment: Please be aware of [the meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: 'I can't imagine how a question can get any worse than this'.. mustn't look.....mustn't look.....mustn't look.....

Comment: Aaaarggghhhh!  I looked..   PHP and 'Can you help me' :(

Comment: The downvotes don't matter now - that question has has been exterminated.

Comment: "Is the question closable?" if your answer is yes either edit it or vote close. Trying to answer a closable question is a bad idea. especially for the unclear , too board one.

Comment: Well personally I don't vote to punish, so no I wouldn't downvote an honest answer based on the state of the question. However I find it difficult to believe that if the question is terrible and/or off-topic that a decent enough answer can be produced so the downvote on the answer may still be justified.

Comment: Rarely, you might see a poor question you can answer where the question can be improved by editing. Do that before answering and you might save yourself some pain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable to downvote answers to very bad and lazy questions.

Answering bad questions encourages the question author to ask *more* of them, rather than revisiting the site's rules and trying to improve the quality of their questions.

At more than 10,000 new questions every day, this is highly relevant to the site's health.

Don't answer bad questions here.

If you *absolutely* feel the need to help a lazy user solve their programming problem that they are too lazy to try and solve themselves (an impulse that will go away over time, I guarantee you), you can engage with them offsite.

Comment: Agreed man.....

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, however it is worthwhile to note that the duplicate contains many opinions about this subject and shows the community as rather split on this point as to whether downvoting is appropriate or not. I would love for your answer to be the official SO answer, however there's a significant fraction of the community who say the opposite and there's no hard fast rule stating yea or nay, at least none that's come up in that duplicate. My opinion is that an answer to a bad question is not useful and therefore downvoted, but other people say other things.